# Content zones not loading on template in interaction studio

Tags: interaction, personalization

i am trying to learn Interaction studio and was building a campaign using template list. after cloning any template i am not getting the option to select a content zone at the bottom of the template and on the visual editor content zone is also not clickable. have imported the sitemap js into interaction studio, added the domain name and also added the website link to launch editor .

Comment: Hi, were you able to fix this issue? I am facing the same problem but can't find the reason or solution.

Comment: I removed the cookies and added the sitemap again from the PLC documentation and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to disable the live button with the draft and then you can easily change the content zone in your existing campaigns.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and the visualstore editor was responding me whit the following error: 
`Response was not OK:`  

My suggestion is to check your Attribute type. 
I had the same problem and I fixed it by changing the type of the attribute from "Object" to "String" 

You can do this by going to the Personalization studio -> Settings -> Attributes and then changing the type of the attribute that could create problems